# I have two sequences,and I want to get the subsequences within them that distinguish the sequences from each other

Tags: python, substring

I have two sequences S, and R.
I want to look for substrings in S that distinguish themselves from R. This means the substrings are not found in R. I want to do the same for R. Meaning I want to find substrings in R that are not in S.

```
Example:
S='acctac'
R='gtgact'

Desired output:
SR=[cc,ta]
RS=[gt,tg,ga,act]
```

Where SR is the set of  distinguishing substrings in S hat are not in R
and RS are the substrings in R that are not in S

Note: a substring is not distinguishing if it contains another substring inside that is also distuingushing.

Any suggestions? In python
the program should be built so that it can be done for sequences of varying lengths.

Comment: Sequences of length what?

Comment: the program should be built so that it can be done for sequences of varying lengths.

Comment: Okay, but you only want it to vary from one run to the next, right? That would make sense with the example you posted above. Otherwise, SR should also have `tac`, `acc`, `acct`, `accta`, etc...

Comment: are you talking about the lengths of the subsequences?

Comment: Yeah, check my edited comment.

Comment: What do you mean calculate SR first?

Comment: yes vary from one run to the next

Comment: the longer the S and R are the morelikely you will have subsequences of different lengths. In the above code RS has the substring 'act' in it beause it was not in SR. 'ac and 'ct' were in SR but 'act was not

Comment: For any non-trivial string length, you *really* need to consider your algorithmic complexity.  Build a trie (or radix tree, if space is an issue) for `S` and `R` and your algorithm is pretty straightforward from there - each "level" constitutes a substring length and you can perform set operations on it.

Comment: I have updated my answer to work with longer string sequences. __Please__ let me know if that is what you want.

Comment: yes i want longer string sequences, thanks

Comment: is that the absolute fastest it can get?

Comment: I have two sequences that are around 1000 in length and its taking forever

Comment: Try limiting the first range to maybe `range(2, len(S)/2)` instead. If my answer was helpful, would you mind [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work). Also, if you are chatting with someone in specific, please use @username so that the person is notified that you said something.

Answer (score 0):

I finally! figured it out. The following works: (although I admit that it *might* be slightly slow for longer sequences. Please try it out and let me know)

```
S='acctac'
R='gtgact'

lst = [S[subs:subs+i] for i in range(2, len(S)) for subs in range(len(S)-i+1) if S[subs:subs+i] not in R]

lst2 = [R[subs:subs+i] for i in range(2, len(R)) for subs in range(len(R)-i+1) if R[subs:subs+i] not in S]

lst = list(set([item for item in lst if all(j not in item for j in lst if j!=item)]))

lst2 = list(set([item for item in lst2 if all(j not in item for j in lst2 if j!=item)]))

>>> print lst
['cc', 'ta']

>>> print lst2
['gt', 'tg', 'ga', 'act']
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, here's an easy way to do it with substrings of the same length.

```
def substr_of_len(n, s):
        return [s[x:x + n] for x in range(0, len(s) - n + 1)]

print [x for x in substr_of_len(2, 'gtgact') if x not in substr_of_len(2, 'acctac')]
>>> ['gt', 'tg', 'ga']

print [x for x in substr_of_len(2, 'acctac') if x not in substr_of_len(2, 'gtgact')]
>>> ['cc', 'ta']

print [x for x in substr_of_len(3, 'gtgact') if x not in substr_of_len(3, 'acctac')]
>>> ['gtg', 'tga', 'gac', 'act']

print [x for x in substr_of_len(3, 'acctac') if x not in substr_of_len(3, 'gtgact')]
>>> ['acc', 'cct', 'cta', 'tac']
```

Comment: Your answer does not give `act` for RS

Comment: Why should it? He said the subsequence length only varies from one run to the next.

Comment: Yes, but how would you go about doing it for `act` if wanted.

Comment: substr_of_len(3, 'gtgact')? oops, this is wrong. you're right.